# late-downvotes received, no reason

Tags: discussion, down-votes, late-answers

One month ago I answered this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693964/in-calculus-how-can-a-function-have-several-different-yet-equal-derivatives/1694063#1694063). From my perspective, even if the question was very simple, I think I manage to find why the OP had trouble understanding the problem and provide a succesful explanation.  ̶I̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶ ̶g̶o̶t̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶u̶p̶v̶o̶t̶e̶ ̶(̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶I̶ ̶a̶s̶s̶u̶m̶e̶ ̶c̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶O̶P̶)

However, last week the question and my answer received downvotes. I am not worried about the downvotes themselves, but I am curious about the reasons behind them.

Has anyone had the same experience? Any ideas of why this downvotes were assigned, besides the question being to easy? Any ideas of why the downvotes came so late?

Needles to say, the downvoters didn't left any comment.

Comment: "I even got an upvote" It does not seem so.   "(which I assume came from the OP)" as OP has 1 point now I doubt they had 15+ then, which is necessary to upvote.  That said, you answer does not seem to answer the question. Now, why it was downvoted then is hard to know.

Comment: The facts about the votes I got were back then, one month ago. The fact they changed almost one month after is exactly what motivated me to make this question...

Comment: The "facts" were **never** as you state. The answer never [added: before this post] was upvoted (except theoretically for less than 5 minutes) contrary to what you claim and virtually certainly it was not upvoted by the OP. Granted  this is tangential, but still you confuse the facts. Note that the answer is at -1 [added: by now it is at 0, but this is due to an upvote received later, as is clear from the point history, presumably because of this post] so it would have had to get two downvotes if it ever were upvoted which it did not.

Comment: No idea about the downvote, In fact, I suspect your answer will be more useful to OP than the other answer. The real issue is the OP don't know how to see the breakdown. In any event, one extra upvote from me (now up 2).

Comment: @achillehui Thanks for appreciating my answer, but the upvote was not needed. The point of my question here was to know about possible reasons to get late downvotes, rather than that specific answer.

Comment: @quid Now that I know how to review the up/down votes, I see that my answer was never upvoted. I apologize for the false information I provided. However, I think my question about late downvotes is still valid, and I certainly regret if anybody thought the important part of my question here was complaining about that specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you received one down vote. I can only guess that someone down voted because your answer was perceived as more confusing than the "obvious" solution, which is to simplify and see the two expressions are the same.

Honestly, from time to time we all get somewhat undeserved down votes. Voting is subjective and I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: OK. I just thought that may be from time to time there were people doing systematic revision of old answers, but if it is not the case then I will definitely not worry about it.